# Is there a way to associate an email with either multiple campaigns or multiple tags?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, campaign, tag

We need to be able to tag an email/social/asset/any type of content with multiple tags.

For example: We have an email coming from our Annual Giving department (a subset of our Capital dept) for BC Law alumni and parents to attend an athletics event. This would need to be tagged/individually associated with:

- Annual giving
- Capital
- BC Law
- Alumni
- Parents
- Event
- Athletics

With the current Campaign setup we would have to create a ton of tags and create a new campaign for each email. Is there a way to do this without creating a "campaign" for every single email we send?